# How to properly align image before mat-error in Angular material?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using angular material for my application and I came across a problem. I am unable to align a image with a mat error message.

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Card Number</mat-label>
  <input type="tel"
         id="cc-number"
         formControlName="cardNumber">
  <mat-error *ngIf="cardError[0]"><img [src]="getAlertImage()">{{cardError[1]}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image: For the above angular material code, its rendered as below]

I cannot make use of matprefix as its tied to mat-form-field only. I am trying to figure out how to align the image with the text. Can someone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would suggest not using images for this sort of thing and utilize one of the fonts you probably already use like below in a pseudo element on the `mat-error` element.

I included examples for both [Material Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons) and [FontAwesome Icons](https://www.fontawesome.com) but I couldn't get the Material Icons font to work here in the snippet editor, but the same CSS will work on your project if you have the Material Icons font used. Just to provide options.

But....if you really want to just stick with using the image, add the css shown in `mat-error` for the flex alignment.

```css
mat-error {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

mat-error:before {
  /* If Font Awesome Icon font */
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 600;
  content: "\f071";
  
  /* If Material Icon font */
  /*
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  content: "warning"
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  */
  
  color: #f00;
  margin-right: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">


<mat-error>Hey I'm an error with an icon.</mat-error>

<br><br>

<mat-error>Ooooh, another error without need for an additional image file.</mat-error>
```

Comment: Nice suggestion to use the ::before selector, but using <br> tags for spacing... XD

Comment: @jarodsmk for a quickie proof of concept on stackoverflow, I feel no shame for it. :D

Comment: You're forgiven :P I'm no saint myself!

Answer (score 0):

What I assume is the image has some issues. As I don't have the image. I have tried with a random image and the error is showing perfectly. what I have done extra is providing the `width` in `img`.
you can try the same.

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input
      type="email"
      matInput
      [formControl]="emailFormControl"
      placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com"
    />
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email') && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')"
    >
      Please enter a valid email address
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
      <img style="width:10px" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/61/61174.png" />
      Email is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: I already have the below css but it didn't work in my case.  .mat-error {
    img {
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      padding-right: 8px;
    }
    color: black;
  }